# How to set GNOME as my default desktop environment?

Tags: gnome, login, lightdm, login-screen

I just downloaded **GNOME-Shell**. And at login screen it's give me to choose to set desktop environment, But I want to set GNOME as my default desktop environment. 
Although I tried the possible suggestions on this site like

```
pnath@ubuntu:~$ sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-shell
[sudo] password for pnath: 
sudo: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults: command not found
pnath@ubuntu:~$
```

And this

```
gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and this:

Open a terminal and `cd` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.d`, create a file called `50-ubuntu.conf` with the following command `sudo nano 50-ubuntu.conf`.

Add the following two lines.

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=gnome
```

then reboot and gnome should be your default session.

When I  tried output is this:

```
pnath@ubuntu:~$ cd /etc/lightdm/lightdm.d
bash: cd: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.d: No such file or directory
pnath@ubuntu:~$
```

this did not change anything

Please give me any other solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(This answer was tested with Ubuntu 14.04. It is probably not useful for newer Ubuntu editions)*

I do not know about ligthDM (@muru confirm that lightDM behave the same), but if you use gdm as display manager the default session is simply the last one you choose (at least, it was --- I hope they didn't change this; can't test now because I removed all desktops minus the gnome-shell one).

To install `gdm` (which, by the way, is the best thing to do if you want gnome-shell --- I had problems with gnome-shell + lightDM), simply

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

If you have it already installed, just

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

will [ask you which display manager to use](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html).

Then when you login, you choose `Gnome` as the desktop you want, and the subsequent login that will be the default.

Comment: Yes when I chose gdm , it's simply change login screen but not theme

Comment: @PriyankaNath I do not understand... if you login choosing "Gnome Desktop" (which is gnome-shell), the next time you login without choosing anything you should go to "Gnome" by default. I can't understand the reference to the theme, which is another thing (and that you can set with `gnome-tweak-tool`).

Comment: "the default session is simply the last one you choose" - also holds for LightDM.

Comment: Yes by default Gnome has started but Icon theme does not changed why ?

Comment: @muru thanks --- I suspected it. PriyankaNath, install and use `gnome-tweak-tool` to change the icon theme --- this is a different matter than default Desktop Environment; none of the changes you comment in the question will do anything in that direction.

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm  has no effect for me. I'm not prompted to chosse any thing. No error meessage.

Comment: @Mehdi the answer was posted for Ubuntu 14.04 (see the date!). A lot of things changed in the Ubuntu graphic stack... I added a warning.